# Data is not getting pushed into firebase if user performs survey offline and kills the app without coming online using react-native-firebase

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

scenario 1:

1. open the app
2. Go Offline
3. perform the survey
4. make sure app is not killed and come online
5. Data gets pushed to firebase once user comes online

Scenario 2:

1. open the app
2. Go Offline
3. perform the survey
4. Kill the app from background
5. Open the app and come online , the data must be pushed to firebase for the surveys which we have performed offline --- Here is the actual problem i am facing , data is not getting pushed to firebase db in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

For scenario 2 to work, the Firebase client will have to write the data to the local disk if there is no connection to the server (known as disk persistence in the Firebase clients). Then when the app restarts, it reads the data from disk, and can retry sending it to the server.

Since scenario 2 isn't working for you, it seems that disk persistence is not enabled. You're not telling/showing us which Firebase database (Firestore or Realtime Database) you're using. But since disk persistence is enabled by default on Firestore, I'm going to assume it's the Realtime Database. To learn how to enable disk persistence there, see https://invertase.io/oss/react-native-firebase/faqs/enabling-database-persistence

Comment: Hi @frank van Puffelen disk persistence is already enabled enabled ,but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Just do the following:

```
export const syncOfflineDataToFirestore = async () => {
  const docRef = await firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection('singledoc-per-device')
    .doc(`doc_name`)
  await docRef.get()
}
```

call the above function in one of the top component where initially app starts.This is will automatically push all the records to firebase.Its bit tricky but works fine.